# When do I know when to use the "scan.close();"

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Abcedarian {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a 6 letter word:");
        String word = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close(); //when would i use this?
        int index = word.length() - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            if (word.charAt(i) <= word.charAt(i + 1)) {
            } else {
                System.out.println("String is not Abecedarian ");
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("String is  Abecedarian ");
    }
}
```

I am working on a code to find Abecedarian words and I was told to use `scan.close()` but I am unsure of what it is and when to use it.

Comment: The quick answer is: Never. Unless you opened it, don't close it. You didn't open the `System.in` `InputStream`, and you should not close it.

Answer (score 3):

Learn to find the Javadoc for classes and methods. Your IDE should have some way of navigating to them.

The Javadoc for `Scanner.close()` says:

Closes this scanner.
If this scanner has not yet been closed then if its underlying readable also implements the `Closeable` interface then the readable's close method will be invoked. If this scanner is already closed then invoking this method will have no effect.
Attempting to perform search operations after a scanner has been closed will result in an `IllegalStateException`.

So you can call close when you have finished using the `Scanner`. But experiment -- try closing it before you've finished with it and see what happens. Try creating a new `Scanner` on `System.in` after you've closed one.

In the particular case of your program, calling close doesn't make a difference, but in general closing resources when you are no longer using them is a good idea.

Comment: You should not `close()` a Scanner on `System.in`. The JVM created that, and the JVM should close it.